# Ansible - Create RDS Instance from most recent existing snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, ansible-2.x, rds, ansible-facts

**ansible 2.7.8**

My goal is this:

> Create a new RDS database, from the most recent existing snapshot of another database.

I found a similar question at ([Ansible: Create new RDS DB from last snapshot of another DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33144866/ansible-create-new-rds-db-from-last-snapshot-of-another-db)) however that solution required creating a new snapshot. I would like to restore from the most recent **already created** snapshot.

So here is what I've done so far... The play used to gather the current snapshot info. I'm using the `rds_snapshot_facts` module (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/rds_snapshot_facts_module.html)

```
  - name : get snap facts
    rds_snapshot_facts  :
      db_instance_identifier: "{{ source_db_name }}"
      region        : "{{ region }}"
      aws_access_key: "{{ access_key }}"
      aws_secret_key: "{{ secret_key }}"
```

It runs successfully, here is example data structure returned from the above play:

```
"snapshots": [
    {
        "allocated_storage": 500,
        "availability_zone": "us-east-1a",
        "db_instance_identifier": "pg-test-01",
        "db_snapshot_arn": "arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:111111111111111:snapshot:rds:pg-test-01-2019-03-01-06-22",
        "db_snapshot_identifier": "rds:pg-test-01-2019-03-01-06-22",
        "dbi_resource_id": "db-hidden",
        "encrypted": false,
        "engine": "postgres",
        "engine_version": "10.6",
        "iam_database_authentication_enabled": false,
        "instance_create_time": "2019-02-27T05:08:47.480000+00:00",
        "license_model": "postgresql-license",
        "master_username": "postgres",
        "option_group_name": "default:postgres-10",
        "percent_progress": 100,
        "port": 5432,
        "processor_features": [],
        "snapshot_create_time": "2019-03-01T06:22:58.771000+00:00",
        "snapshot_type": "automated",
        "status": "available",
        "storage_type": "gp2",
        "tags": {},
        "vpc_id": "vpc-hidden"
    },
    {
        "allocated_storage": 500,
        "availability_zone": "us-east-1a",
        "db_instance_identifier": "pg-test-01",
        "db_snapshot_arn": "arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:111111111111111:snapshot:rds:pg-test-01-2019-03-02-06-32",
        "db_snapshot_identifier": "rds:pg-test-01-2019-03-02-06-32",
        "dbi_resource_id": "db-hidden",
        "encrypted": false,
        "engine": "postgres",
        "engine_version": "10.6",
        "iam_database_authentication_enabled": false,
        "instance_create_time": "2019-02-27T05:08:47.480000+00:00",
        "license_model": "postgresql-license",
        "master_username": "postgres",
        "option_group_name": "default:postgres-10",
        "percent_progress": 100,
        "port": 5432,
        "processor_features": [],
        "snapshot_create_time": "2019-03-02T06:32:42.325000+00:00",
        "snapshot_type": "automated",
        "status": "available",
        "storage_type": "gp2",
        "tags": {},
        "vpc_id": "vpc-hidden"
    },
    {
        "allocated_storage": 500,
        "availability_zone": "us-east-1a",
        "db_instance_identifier": "pg-test-01",
        "db_snapshot_arn": "arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:111111111111111:snapshot:rds:pg-test-01-2019-03-03-06-33",
        "db_snapshot_identifier": "rds:pg-test-01-2019-03-03-06-33",
        "dbi_resource_id": "db-hidden",
        "encrypted": false,
        "engine": "postgres",
        "engine_version": "10.6",
        "iam_database_authentication_enabled": false,
        "instance_create_time": "2019-02-27T05:08:47.480000+00:00",
        "license_model": "postgresql-license",
        "master_username": "postgres",
        "option_group_name": "default:postgres-10",
        "percent_progress": 100,
        "port": 5432,
        "processor_features": [],
        "snapshot_create_time": "2019-03-03T06:33:06.463000+00:00",
        "snapshot_type": "automated",
        "status": "available",
        "storage_type": "gp2",
        "tags": {},
        "vpc_id": "vpc-hidden"
    },
    {
        "allocated_storage": 500,
        "availability_zone": "us-east-1a",
        "db_instance_identifier": "pg-test-01",
        "db_snapshot_arn": "arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:111111111111111:snapshot:rds:pg-test-01-2019-03-04-06-32",
        "db_snapshot_identifier": "rds:pg-test-01-2019-03-04-06-32",
        "dbi_resource_id": "db-hidden",
        "encrypted": false,
        "engine": "postgres",
        "engine_version": "10.6",
        "iam_database_authentication_enabled": false,
        "instance_create_time": "2019-02-27T05:08:47.480000+00:00",
        "license_model": "postgresql-license",
        "master_username": "postgres",
        "option_group_name": "default:postgres-10",
        "percent_progress": 100,
        "port": 5432,
        "processor_features": [],
        "snapshot_create_time": "2019-03-04T06:32:30.227000+00:00",
        "snapshot_type": "automated",
        "status": "available",
        "storage_type": "gp2",
        "tags": {},
        "vpc_id": "vpc-hidden"
    },
    {
        "allocated_storage": 500,
        "availability_zone": "us-east-1a",
        "db_instance_identifier": "pg-test-01",
        "db_snapshot_arn": "arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:111111111111111:snapshot:rds:pg-test-01-2019-03-05-06-32",
        "db_snapshot_identifier": "rds:pg-test-01-2019-03-05-06-32",
        "dbi_resource_id": "db-hidden",
        "encrypted": false,
        "engine": "postgres",
        "engine_version": "10.6",
        "iam_database_authentication_enabled": false,
        "instance_create_time": "2019-02-27T05:08:47.480000+00:00",
        "license_model": "postgresql-license",
        "master_username": "postgres",
        "option_group_name": "default:postgres-10",
        "percent_progress": 100,
        "port": 5432,
        "processor_features": [],
        "snapshot_create_time": "2019-03-05T06:32:57.880000+00:00",
        "snapshot_type": "automated",
        "status": "available",
        "storage_type": "gp2",
        "tags": {},
        "vpc_id": "vpc-hidden"
    },
    {
        "allocated_storage": 500,
        "availability_zone": "us-east-1a",
        "db_instance_identifier": "pg-test-01",
        "db_snapshot_arn": "arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:111111111111111:snapshot:snapshot-pg-test-01-2019-03-06-02-22",
        "db_snapshot_identifier": "snapshot-pg-test-01-2019-03-06-02-22",
        "dbi_resource_id": "db-hidden",
        "encrypted": false,
        "engine": "postgres",
        "engine_version": "10.6",
        "iam_database_authentication_enabled": false,
        "instance_create_time": "2019-02-27T05:08:47.480000+00:00",
        "license_model": "postgresql-license",
        "master_username": "postgres",
        "option_group_name": "default:postgres-10",
        "percent_progress": 100,
        "port": 5432,
        "processor_features": [],
        "snapshot_create_time": "2019-03-06T02:23:35.039000+00:00",
        "snapshot_type": "manual",
        "status": "available",
        "storage_type": "gp2",
        "tags": {},
        "vpc_id": "vpc-hidden"
    }
]
```

So with the above info, I would like to do some logic against it and create a new db.

I know how to create a db from a snapshot already:

```
  - name : Restore RDS from snapshot
    rds  :
      command           : restore
      instance_name     : "{{ new_db_name }}"
      snapshot          : "{{ snapshot_name }}"
      instance_type     : "db.t2.medium"
      subnet            : my_subnet_grp 
      wait              : yes
      wait_timeout      : 1600
      region             : "{{ region }}"
      aws_access_key: "{{ access_key }}"
      aws_secret_key: "{{ secret_key }}"
```

However, in my case I would like the variable `"{{ snapshot_name }}"` to be filled in dynamically from the facts collected.

Essentially the pseudo code logic would be something like:

```
db_snapshot_identifier where status=available and max(snapshot_create_time)
```

I'm really not sure where to even start constructing that logic for an Ansible operation, so any help or point in the right direction is welcomed - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jinja2 is what you need.

Use a `selectattr` filter to only select available snapshots.

Then `sort` filter to order the results by `snapshot_create_time`

Finally the `last` filter to pick the last result and use that in the `rds` module.

There's lots of good information in the [Jinja2 documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/)

```
- name : get snap facts
  rds_snapshot_facts  :
    db_instance_identifier: "{{ source_db_name }}"
    region        : "{{ region }}"
    aws_access_key: "{{ access_key }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ secret_key }}"
  register: snapshot_facts

- name: get latest snapshot facts
  set_fact:
    latest_snapshot: '{{ snapshot_facts.snapshots | 
                        selectattr("status", "equalto", "available") |
                        sort(attribute="snapshot_create_time") |
                        last }}'

- name : Restore RDS from snapshot
  rds  :
    command           : restore
    instance_name     : "{{ new_db_name }}"
    snapshot          : "{{ latest_snapshot.db_snapshot_identifier }}"
    instance_type     : "db.t2.medium"
    subnet            : my_subnet_grp 
    wait              : yes
    wait_timeout      : 1600
    region            : "{{ region }}"
    aws_access_key: "{{ access_key }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ secret_key }}"
```

Comment: You sir, are the best. Thank you for sharing your knowledge.